# Phrasal verb: Wash upon

Tags: phrasal-verbs, songs

Non-native english speaker here. The context is songwriting.

Can a tide "wash upon" someone or something?

Comment: *Can a tide "wash upon" someone or something?* Not without a full sentence and some context - could you provide these?

Comment: I suggest "wash *over*". But a tide isn't the same thing as a wave, or the sea, and would be used to express something *other* than water, such as emotion.

Comment: @Greybeard out of honest curiosity, what'd happen if I shared the lyrics here and someone else were to use them? People steal the craziest things, even home-made literary garbage.

Comment: @WeatherVane over is one syllable, upon is two and the latter both sounded and fit better "the meter" (?)

Comment: "Over" has two syllables. With no context, how could anyone have known about the meter?

Comment: @WeatherVane you're absolutely right and I did not mean to imply that your suggestion was not valuable. I was trying to explain why I felt "upon" was better than "over". I see why it's come across that way. I should stop using questionable ad-filled websites for English questions (such as the one that told me "over" is one syllable).

Comment: @WeatherVane regarding the context, as I mentioned to Greybeard, I'm unsure about the implications of posting something in the works. Not for the value, which might be laughable, but it's something I care about and I wouldn't want to see it misused to the point I won't be able to use it myself in the future. If that makes sense.

Comment: In 'The sea washed gently upon/over the untrodden beach', which are both fine, it is arguable that the central structure is verb + prepositional phrase rather than phrasal verb + direct object. Admittedly, the preposition-or-is-it? may be deleted, leaving transitive _wash_ (you'd have to move the adverb), but then 'He appealed against the charges' is usually not seen as including a multi-word verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tide or waves may wash upon the shore. The use of *upon* rather than *on* gives the sense of the water *rising* to where it washes (=flows) over the shore. The use of *wash* implies a repetitive phenomenon. Both are appropriate to waves and tides, waves on a shore usually rising and falling rapidly with periods measured in seconds and the tide being a special case of a slowly repeating wave of long period measured in hours.

> If water washes somewhere, it flows there, usually repeatedly
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wash)

In song writing, poetry or sensual literature, the phrase may be used. I need quote none of the many examples to be found by online search for "tide washes upon the shore").

Historically "wash upon the shore" was more popular than now. Here is the google ngram:

[image]

To give you just one representative technical oceanographic example far removed from creative wordplay, please consider:

> Unlike the situation in exposed beaches where waves wash upon the shore and replenish the interstitial oxygenated water supply by gravity, the submerged sand has only diffusion processes and currents ...
>
> https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=KRsr4gVHdPgC&q=%22waves+wash+upon%22&dq=%22waves+wash+upon%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSsK2-xM_sAhXPilwKHeLQB4sQ6AEwB3oECAkQAg

This technical prose relies on *upon* (the movement onto the shore, implying later movement off the shore) for its meaning. Only when water subsides is water drawn down into the sand. If the water merely moved *on* the shore it would not necessarily subside, and no new oxygenated water would be drawn down into the sand.

I conclude that you are justified in using the phrase both by artistic precedent, by previous usage, and by reasoned contemporary technical usage. The phrase also has an easily understandable and not too wide a range of meaning within the context of a song.

Comment: Thank you! I believe I did my homework, as it were, but I suspect my search results are either skewed or I couldn't find anything conclusive (to me, anyway). ngram looks great. RhymeZone is usually my first - and only - choice.

Comment: I enjoyed that one. Took me back to my professional times.